# Filter a string before creating an Option[String]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

I have the following where obj is a `JsObject`:

```
val approx_pieces: Option[String] = (obj \ "approx_pieces").asOpt[String]
```

This code will create a `Some("0")` if the approx pieces is "0" in the database.

How can I change it so that it creates `None` when the string is "0"?

Comment: Some("0").flatMap(x => if (x == "0") None else Some(x))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have an `Option`, and you don't want to use the value in certain cases, then `filter` is your most idiomatic choice:

```
val one = Option("1")
val zero = Option("0")
one.filter(_ != "0") //Some("1")
zero.filter(_ != "0") //None
```

Using this method, your solution would be:

```
(obj \ "approx_pieces").asOpt[String].filter(_ != "0")
```

Alternatively, you can do this with a `match` statement.  The `JsValue` subtypes in Play all have an `unapply` method, so you can directly match on them:

```
(obj \ "approx_pieces") match {
    case JsString(num) if num != "0" => Some(num)
    case _ => None
}
```

You might also be interested in the `collect` method:

```
(obj \ "approx_pieces").asOpt[String] collect {
    case num if num != "0" => num
}
```

`collect` is nice because it allows you to filter and map at the same time.

You can use both of the above methods together, too:

```
Option(obj \ "approx_pieces") collect {
    case JsString(num) if num != "0" => num
}
```

Comment: Only one option is doing what the OP asked for - they asked for None when 0, not filtering, I'd guess leading to a zip.

Comment: @EdStaub All the methods here return `None` when 0 and `Some(value)` otherwise, which I think is what OP wanted.  `filter` on an `Option` returns `None` if the filter function returns false, as does `collect` when the partial function is not defined.

Comment: Right - sorry.  I'm always working a level up, with a collection of Options, and projected ;-).